# BufferedReader output in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, bufferedreader

I am trying to call a line from `BufferedReader` its in another class I want to be able to output the result in my `JTextArea` which is in my main class

**Here is my Main Class:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Process.*;

public class FTP {
    public static void main (String []args){
            Runnable runner = new Runnable(){
                public void run()
                {

                    LookAndFeel nimbusLook = new LookAndFeel();
                    nimbusLook.NimbusLookAndFeel();

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BNA FTP Diagnose");
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    frame.setSize(540, 420);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLocation(150, 150);


                    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

                    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
                    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
                    final JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
                    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);


                    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
                    menuBar.add(new JPanel());
                    menuBar.add(helpMenu);
                    final JMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("About");
                    helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);



                    JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                    JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("FTP Diagnose", JLabel.CENTER);
                    titleLabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 14));
                    titleLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    titlePanel.add(titleLabel);

                    JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                    frame.add(gridPanel);

                    JPanel vendorPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                    gridPanel.add(vendorPanel);

                    final String vendor [] = {"LLesiant" ,"WK-CCH", "Proquest", "Notes", "Research Institute of America", "Thomson", 
                            "BNAI PDF Processing", " TM Portfolios to Indexing", "Postscript to PRODLOGIN1", "www.firstdoor.net", "psp.bna.com", "WEST", "LexisNexis", "McArdle Printing Company", 
                            "Breaking News Email", "Ex Libris", "Pandora", "Bloomberg Law", "Acquire Media Site 1", "Acquire Media Site 2", "Quicksite", "QA Quicksite"};
                    final JComboBox vendorList = new JComboBox(vendor);
                    vendorPanel.add(vendorList);

                    JPanel diagnoseButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
                    gridPanel.add(diagnoseButtonPanel);
                    final JButton diagnoseButton = new JButton("Diagnose");
                    diagnoseButtonPanel.add(diagnoseButton);


                    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    JPanel commandPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
                    centerPanel.add(commandPanel);


                    final JTextArea commandResultArea = new JTextArea(7, 0);
                    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(commandResultArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                    commandPanel.add(scroll);
                    commandResultArea.setEditable(false);




                    ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener(){

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)

                        {
                            int selectedIndex = vendorList.getSelectedIndex();

                            String llesiant = "ftp.llesiant.com";
                            String wkCCH = "FTP1.cch.com";
                            String proquest = "ftp.proquest.com";
                            String notes = "notes5.bna.com";


                            //String lineThree = null;

                            CommandClass readCommand = new CommandClass();

                            if (selectedIndex == 0)
                            {
                                readCommand.getCommand(llesiant);
                            }
                            else if (selectedIndex == 1)
                            {
                                readCommand.getCommand(wkCCH);
                            }
                            else if (selectedIndex == 2)
                            {
                                readCommand.getCommand(proquest);
                            }
                            else if (selectedIndex == 3)
                            {
                                readCommand.getCommand(notes);
                            }

                        }

                    };
                    diagnoseButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);

                    ActionListener exitListener = new ActionListener (){

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent el)
                        {

                            if (el.getSource()== exitMenuItem)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FTP Program will exit now!");
                                System.exit(0);
                            }

                        }

                    };

                    exitMenuItem.addActionListener(exitListener);

                    ActionListener aboutListener = new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent al)
                        {

                            if (al.getSource()== aboutMenuItem)

                            {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This Software was made for Editors to. \nDiagnose BNA Bloomberg client FTP site.");

                            }
                        }

                    };
                    aboutMenuItem.addActionListener(aboutListener);             
                    }

            };
            EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);

        }

}
```

**Here is my CommandClass:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class CommandClass {




    public String line;



    public void getCommand(String ftpSite)

    {


        String command = "ping ";


        try
        {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command +ftpSite);

        BufferedReader readOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (p.getInputStream()));


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FTP is connected");

        while ((line = readOutput.readLine()) != null)
        {

                System.out.println(line);   

        }
        readOutput.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }





}
```

**Here is my Look and Feel class:**

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class LookAndFeel {


    public void NimbusLookAndFeel()
    {

        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }


    }




}
```

What i am trying to do :Output prints out fine in the console but I wanna be able to print it out in the JTextArea in the mail class also I tried returning the value of the string line but it seems to keep coming back with null. If what i am trying to do is not possible. Is there a way to the have my JTextArea.setText to (commandCLass)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Improve your `getCommand` method like this to return proper `String` and use that return value in your main class to display in the `JTextArea`

```
public String getCommand(String ftpSite){
    String command = "ping ";
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    try{
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command +ftpSite);
         //BufferedReader readOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (p.getInputStream()));
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader (p.getInputStream());
        int outputChar = 0;
        while((outputChar = ir.read()) != -1){
            output.append((char)outputChar);
        if(!ir.ready()){ // If the next read is not guarenteed, come out of loop.
            break;
        }
            }
          ir.close();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FTP is connected");
         //while ((line = readOutput.readLine()) != null){
              //System.out.println(line);   
              //output.append(line).append("\n");
         //}
         //readOutput.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

**if-else block in FTP class**

```
                CommandClass readCommand = new CommandClass();

                        if (selectedIndex == 0)
                        {
                            commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(llesiant));
                        }
                        else if (selectedIndex == 1)
                        {
                            commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(wkCCH));
                        }
                        else if (selectedIndex == 2)
                        {
                            commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(proquest));
                        }
                        else if (selectedIndex == 3)
                        {
                           commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(notes));
                        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you needed to inherent the FTP class by extending it and also why you had to declare the the class as string which returns a value. and whats the purpose of the output string seems like its set to nothing at the top. I would really appreciated i am trying to learn this

Comment: I have not inherited `FTP` class. I had modified `getCommand` method in the `CommandClass`. In your `FTP` class, the **if-else** ladder will be changed as shown in my post. Updated my post.

Comment: also I have a question if i were to change the command from ping to ftp It doesn't print out any message saying the ftp is connected usally when you type in ftp on cmd or unix and the site it says its connected is it because i haven't outputStream for my command and if I wanted to show a message when ftp is connected how do i do that or     how do i print out whatever usually gets printer out when you run the ftp command on cmd or unix Thanks a million

Comment: I just tried it with the ftp command and didn't get any response does it have to be a url or can it be something like "ftp.llesiant.com" I didn't get any response on the JTextArea when i tried for one of the ftp site that i have listed in code

Comment: Using `InputStreamReader` I'm able to achieve that. Not `BufferedReader`. Updating my answer.

Comment: can you give me and example please

Comment: I just tried it. The application just hangs for a while and nothing happens

Comment: I meant to say when you click the diagnose button in the GUI it just hangs it self.

Comment: Check with **WK-CCH**. **LLesiant** is giving a request timeout after some time.

Comment: It seems like in the top code you have String command set to ping i set mine to ftp and it just hangs when i click the diagnose button and doesn't do anything is the users name prompt are you getting that in the console or the JTextArea

Comment: I tried to print it out also on the console but it doesn't do that either

Comment: I got it. You have to check with [`Reader.ready`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready()) also. Answer updated and now it is working.

Comment: I don't see the updated code at the top Reader ready is that from a IO class?

Comment: Check the **if condition inside the while loop**. `Reader` is also from `java.io` package.

Comment: Also it doesn't return host not found for notes it just freezes

Comment: In command prompt also it is not getting connected. It is just showing ftp prompt but not giving result of any command. I don't know how to handle that situation.

Comment: Yeah in the command prompt it just says host not found but on JtextArea it doesn't say anything

Answer (score 0):

FTP Class:

I made it so that when you pinged the server, it would return a string.
You can modify it to actively edit the text in the JTextField, but this works fine.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Process.*;

public class FTP {



  public static void main (String []args)
  {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable(){



      public void run()
      {

        LookAndFeel nimbusLook = new LookAndFeel();
        nimbusLook.NimbusLookAndFeel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BNA FTP Diagnose");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(540, 420);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);


        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        final JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);


        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(new JPanel());
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);
        final JMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("About");
        helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);



        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("FTP Diagnose", JLabel.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 14));
        titleLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        titlePanel.add(titleLabel);

        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        frame.add(gridPanel);

        JPanel vendorPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        gridPanel.add(vendorPanel);

        final String vendor [] = {"LLesiant" ,"WK-CCH", "Proquest", "Notes", "Research Institute of America", "Thomson", 
          "BNAI PDF Processing", " TM Portfolios to Indexing", "Postscript to PRODLOGIN1", "www.firstdoor.net", "psp.bna.com", "WEST", "LexisNexis", "McArdle Printing Company", 
          "Breaking News Email", "Ex Libris", "Pandora", "Bloomberg Law", "Acquire Media Site 1", "Acquire Media Site 2", "Quicksite", "QA Quicksite"};
        final JComboBox vendorList = new JComboBox(vendor);
        vendorPanel.add(vendorList);

        JPanel diagnoseButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        gridPanel.add(diagnoseButtonPanel);
        final JButton diagnoseButton = new JButton("Diagnose");
        diagnoseButtonPanel.add(diagnoseButton);


        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JPanel commandPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        centerPanel.add(commandPanel);


        final JTextArea commandResultArea = new JTextArea(7, 0);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(commandResultArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        commandPanel.add(scroll);
        commandResultArea.setEditable(false);




        ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener(){

          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)

          {
            int selectedIndex = vendorList.getSelectedIndex();

            String llesiant = "ftp.llesiant.com";
            String wkCCH = "FTP1.cch.com";
            String proquest = "ftp.proquest.com";
            String notes = "notes5.bna.com";


            //String lineThree = null;

            CommandClass readCommand = new CommandClass();

            if (selectedIndex == 0)
            {
              commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(llesiant)); //these return strings

            }
            else if (selectedIndex == 1)
            {
              commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(wkCCH));
            }
            else if (selectedIndex == 2)
            {
              commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(proquest));
            }
            else if (selectedIndex == 3)
            {
              commandResultArea.setText(readCommand.getCommand(notes));
            }

          }

        };
        diagnoseButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);

        ActionListener exitListener = new ActionListener (){

          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent el)
          {

            if (el.getSource()== exitMenuItem)
            {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FTP Program will exit now!");
              System.exit(0);
            }

          }

        };

        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(exitListener);

        ActionListener aboutListener = new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent al)
          {

            if (al.getSource()== aboutMenuItem)

            {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This Software was made for Editors to. \nDiagnose BNA Bloomberg client FTP site.");

            }
          }

        };
        aboutMenuItem.addActionListener(aboutListener);             
      }

    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);

  }

}
```

Command Class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class CommandClass extends FTP {




  public String line, output = "";



  public String getCommand(String ftpSite)

  {


    String command = "ping ";


    try
    {
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command +ftpSite);

      BufferedReader readOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (p.getInputStream()));


      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FTP is connected");

      while ((line = readOutput.readLine()) != null)
      {

        System.out.println(line);   
        output += line + "\n";

      }
      readOutput.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return output;
  }





}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you needed to inherent the FTP class by extending it and also why you had to declare the the class as string which returns a value. and whats the purpose of the output string seems like its set to nothing at the top. I would really appreciated i am trying to learn this.